# number theory application on java

Tags: number-theory, greatest-common-divisor

I want to simplify fractionals in an efficient way by using number theory. How to propose an efficient approach to simplify the numbers?

```
        int gcd = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a && i <= b; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Euclid's algorithm: Calculate a % b and replace a with the remainder; then b % a and replace b, until the remainder is zero, then the divisor is the gcd. No need for the for loop iterating over all the numbers

Comment: while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
   if (a > b) {
    a = a % b;
   } else {
    b = b % a;
   }
  } i manage to write this part but i couldnt find where to replace and how to refresh gcd

Comment: Looks quite good - replace the for loop with while. The gcd is the varible (a or b) that is not 0 at the end. Or just use gcd = a + b

Comment: Further possibility for improvement: After a = a % b => a is always smaller than b and vice versa. So you know, after a%b comes b%a and so on. You could either compare a>b only at the beginning or let it run one 'false branch' (one comparison and one jump or 50% unnecessary modulo division) - this would not change the variables, e.g. 4 % 7 = 4